# Error calling azure function with model as parameter

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I keep getting the error:

```
Exception while executing function: Functions.InsertItem -> Exception binding parameter 'newItem' -> No value was provided for parameter 'newItem'
```

when calling the below azure function.

I'm actually using the azure portal to develp, no VS.

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run( HttpRequestMessage req,
[HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "POST")] Item newItem)
{                  
     return newItem == null
         ? req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Please pass an item in the request body")
         : req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Hello " + newItem.Name);
} 

public class Item
{  
    public string Name { get; set; }    
}
```

Any idea what is wrong? Thanks!

Comment: In portal we need to define the bindings in the integrate tab. And portal does not require the HttpTrigger attribute.

Comment: You may remove your attribute, it has no value in the portal (scripted `csx` functions). Please share your `function.json`.

Comment: Ok so I went to the Integrate tab, and edited function.json 

`{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "name": "req",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in"
    },
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "name": "item",
      "type": "Item",
      "direction": "in"
    },
    {
      "name": "$return",
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}` but stlil getting the error (Didn't find a proper example on how to define the binding, so I tried with what seemed the obvious.)

Comment: Rather put your json to the question, so that it's formatted and visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change your `function.json` to the following:

```json
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "name": "newItem",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in"
    },
    {
      "name": "$return",
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

You shouldn't have a separate entry for `newItem`, just declare it as the trigger.

Answer (score 0):

For example if we want to post a JSON object to function as below

```
{
  "Item":
   { 
      "Name" : "test details"
   }
}
```

Then the function has to be updated as below and you need to use a JSON Deserializer if you want to do explicit conversion or use dynamic object in the code to deserialize the request.

```
using System.Net;

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");


    // Get request body
    dynamic data = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();

    // Set name to query string or body data
    string name = data.Item?.Name;

    return name == null
        ? req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body")
        : req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Hello " + name);
}

public class Item
{
    public string Name{get;set;}
}
```

Below is the binding details from function.json

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "name": "req",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in"
    },
    {
      "name": "$return",
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

Comment: I have made it work this way, deserializing the json object in the function, but I was trying to send it as a parameter to the function.

Comment: If you want the function to have the signature as "newItem" then we need to update the binding from "req" to "newitem". Or you can leave it as default "req". Either ways there would be parsing required in function to access the value.